# Flask-socketio websocket connection timeout

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

I am setting up a web application using Flask and Flask-socketio for Websockets, using eventlet as recommended in the documentation.

The purpose is to create a coding platform where users can subscribe, join the current challenge and for each exercise can submit their own solution (a piece of code) which will then be assessed for correctness on the server via test cases (they write a function, given some input it must give a specific output, if it doesn't count zero score).

The issue is that some server-side computation in executing the uploaded code may take several seconds to complete before returning the output to the client. In this case, the client disconnects upon receiving the data from the server, after the long wait. You can see below some code which reproduces the issue, the time.sleep represents the long server side computation, which will cause the client to disconnect and reconnect.

Note: in the code I put 40 seconds of sleep, that is to have the client disconnect every time, for a smaller time (say between 10 and 20), sometimes it works fine and sometimes it disconnects.

Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_socketio import emit, disconnect

import time
import random

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(flask_app, async_mode='eventlet')


webpage = '''
<html>
    <body>    
        <p id="demo">Some content</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="do_on_server()">Do server-side computation</button>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            var socket = io();
            function do_on_server(){
                socket.emit('do_on_server', {});
            }

            socket.on('feedback', feedback);
            function feedback(data){
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data["msg"];
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
'''


@flask_app.route('/')
def index():
    return webpage


@socketio.on('do_on_server')
def do_on_server(json): 

    print('starting computation')
    #long computation
    time.sleep(40)
    print('done computing')

    emit('feedback', {'msg': random.random()})


@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('Connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('Disconnecting')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   socketio.run(flask_app)
```

Console output:

```
>python socket_timeout.py
Connected
starting computation
done computing
Disconnecting
Connected
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking - there's nowhere in the sample code that you've tried to add a timeout? I think if you're using `time.sleep(n)` to simulate the 'long processing', that might block any attempt at cutting a request short after a timeout. Please demonstrate how you're currently attempting the timeout functionality.

Comment: I have edited the question leaving the timeout part out as it was not strictly relevant with the question at hand, it was just there to give some background on how the webapp works. The issue is that upon too long requests, the client disconnects while I would rather it to stay connected

Comment: Using `time.sleep()` will block not only the client but the entire server process with all of its ongoing tasks. A long computation will cause the same effect, so you should design your application so that any CPU intensive tasks are ideally done in other processes. An easier solution that might also work is to add frequent calls to `socketio.sleep(0)` while the long calculation takes place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The intensive tasks are done in new threads, is that enough or I would optimally need to create a new process? And what would be the effect of adding `socketio.sleep(0)`, if I decided to stay within the same process?

Comment: Looking deeper into `socketio.sleep(0)` I found [this](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/692) where it is explained why it works. It solved the problem in my case, thank you!